# Unit testing of Spring ApplicationEventPublisher fails to consume the events

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I want to integration test a Spring Boot 1.5.4 service that uses an @EventListener. My problem is: when the test is run, the events are correctly published, but they are not consumed.

My ultimate purpose is to use a @TransactionEventListener, but for simplicity I start with an @EventListener.

Here is my service class:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  private static final Logger logger = // ...

  private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

  @Autowired
  public MyService(ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher) {
    this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
  }

  @Transactional
  public void publish() {
    logger.warn("Publishing!");
    eventPublisher.publishEvent(new MyEvent());
  }

  // @TransactionalEventListener
  @EventListener
  public void consume(MyEvent event) {
    logger.warn("Consuming!");      // this is never executed in the test
  }

  public static class MyEvent {
  }
}
```

Here is my JUnit test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class MyServiceIT {

  @Autowired
  MyService myService;

  @Test
  public void doSomething() {
    myService.publish();
  }

  static class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
      return new MyService(eventPublisher());
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher() {
      ApplicationEventPublisher ctx = new GenericApplicationContext();
      ((AbstractApplicationContext)ctx).refresh();
      return ctx;
    }
  }
}
```

Note: the call to refresh() prevents an IllegalStateException with message "ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context" from occurring.

Does anyone have a clue? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the solution was: keep the event consumer method in another bean than the event producer method. That is, extract method consume(MyEvent) from class MyService into a new @Service class MyConsumer.